# DataReceived Event handler not receiving messages

Tags: c#-3.0, serial-port

I'm using the below code to receive the messages using serial port event handler. But it dosent receives any.I am not getting errors. The code breaks in "`string msg = comport.Readline()`" Am i doing something wrong ?

```
public partial class SerialPortScanner : Form
{
    private SerialPort comPort = new SerialPort();

    public SerialPortScanner()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comPort.Open();
        comPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(comPort_DataReceived);

    }


    void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (comPort.IsOpen == true)
        {
            string msg = comPort.ReadLine();
            MessageBox.Show(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "The code breaks?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataReceived event is raised on a secondary thread when data is received from the SerialPort object. Because this event is raised on a secondary thread, and not the main thread, attempting to modify some elements in the main thread, such as UI elements, could raise a threading exception.

Source : [Check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=VS.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`ReadLine` depends on having a [`NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.newline.aspx) character.  You might have better luck with the `Read` method.  See also the `BytesToRead` property.